# How do I separate by comma this string?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to separate the following string by comma and get the chunks down below. What's the most elegant solution in C#? [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) detects also internal commas, of course.

```
"'_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)', '_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)', #349, #1 "
```

The result should be:

```
'_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)'
'_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)'
#349
#1
```

Thanks.

Comment: is there always a whitespace character after the comma you want to split on?

Comment: treat it as csv data, and tell the csv parser that the fields are enclosed-by `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string aux = "'_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)', '_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)', #349, #1 ";
var result = Regex.Split(aux, ("(?!\\B'[^']*),(?![^']*'\\B)"));
```

**EDIT**

This was not getting the `" '', '' "` because '' doesn't contain anything.

Solution:

```
string pattern = "('[^']+'|[^',^\\s]+|['']+)";
string str1 = "'_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)', '_82X5_00_11 (2,RAL 7035)', #349, #1 ";
string str2 = "'', '', #344, #334";
var result1 = Regex.Matches(str1, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
var result2 = Regex.Matches(str2, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: It does not work for the following string: `" '', '', #344, #334 "`. It returns 3 chunks instead of 4. Do you know why?

Comment: Wow that's tricky because of the '', '' without anything between the ' char

Comment: @Alberto Added solution

Comment: What about this? `"'TS8 8245.500 (2)', 'TS8 8245.500 (2)', 'PART-TS8 8245.500 (2)-DESC', ( #596 )"` It should return only 4 elements, not 6.